# Reading BufferedInputStream from named Linux pipe only works once

Tags: java, linux, pipe, javax.imageio, bufferedinputstream

I'm desperate,...I have tried and search a lot, no luck. Please help

Bit of a Background:
    Using a raspberry Pi 3, I develop a webcam streaming server as I don't want the ones available. With raspistill the fps is very low (4fps), that is why I look into v4l2 option for streaming the webcam. For this I output the mjpeg video into a pipe.

Reading from this pipe, the first jpeg image is shown, but consecutive reads return null.

To investigate this further I made a small demo program - same result.

Here the code I use:

**Iterating 20 times reading from bufferedinputstream**

```
private void standardRead()
    {
        BufferedInputStream bis = null;
        try {
            bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(image_path)));           


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {         
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Is mark supported? "+bis.markSupported());

        try {
            for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
            {
                readingImage(bis,i);
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(250);
            }

        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {            
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**Read method (enhanced with some System.out)**

```
private void readingImage(BufferedInputStream bis,int iteration) throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("Available bytes to read:"+bis.available());
        System.out.println("Reading image"+iteration);

        BufferedImage read = ImageIO.read(bis);

        if(read!=null){
            System.out.println(read.getRGB(25, 25)+" h:"+read.getHeight());System.out.println();
        }else
        {
            System.out.println("image is null");
        }
        read = null;
    }
```

What I have already tried:
 - Creating a new BufferedInputStream for each iteration 
 - Closing and creating  a new BufferedInputStream
 - Tried using mark and reset (no luck)
 - Reading from the stream using read instead of ImageIO (reads for ever obviously with about 20fps)

When I execute the program, v4l2 informs that frames are consumed, therefore the pipe is being emptied/read by the java program so new frames can be fed into it.
Only the first image and only during the first execution of the program gives me one image back. A second execution of the program gives null for the first image too.

Here an example output:

```
Is mark supported? true
Available bytes to read:65536
Reading image0
image is null
Available bytes to read:73720
Reading image1
image is null
Available bytes to read:73712
Reading image2
image is null
Available bytes to read:73704
Reading image3
image is null
Available bytes to read:73696
Reading image4
image is null
Available bytes to read:73688
Reading image5
image is null
```

One note, if any helpful. For the ImageIO.read(InputStream) function, Java doc states something strange which I can't understand:

> (...) The InputStream is wrapped in an ImageInputStream. If no
>   registered ImageReader claims to be able to read the resulting stream,
>   null is returned (...)

Thanks in advance for your help and advice.

Comment: Some image formats do not have an implicit end, so ImageIO reads the *entire* InputStream.  PNG is one such format.

Answer (score 1):

One sleepless night later, I got something working.

Eureka: I stream 1000 frames using v4l2 library into a linux pipe and can read all 1000 frames. With saving each file to a directory it takes about 103 seconds aka 10fps. No single frame skipped.

Here is how:

```
private void ReadImages(File path)
    {
        BufferedInputStream bis = null;
        int index = 0;

        ImageReader reader = null;

            try {
                bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(path));
                ImageInputStream stream = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(bis);

                while(bis.available()>0)
                {
                    if(gotReader(stream))
                    {
                        reader = ImageIO.getImageReaders(stream).next();
                        reader.setInput(stream);
                        BufferedImage read = reader.read(index);
                        System.out.println("Image height"+read.getHeight() +" image width:"+read.getWidth()) ;

                        stream.flush();                 
                    index = 0;
                    }

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                //e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

Tip: flush the stream frequently and reset the index. Without flushing the growing memory breaks the performance dramatically.

Tip: Standard ImageIO does not read BGR3, RGB3,YU12,YUYV,YV12,YVYU but H264 and MJPEG

Tip: Reader is tested with

```
if(ImageIO.getImageReaders(stream).hasNext())
```